# ReactJS: How do I access my models in event handlers without binding?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have a ReactJS component that represents a "Document" containing "Paragraph"s, each containing "Sentences" which I want rendered into `contenteditable` `span`s.

```
var paragraphData = [{
  id: 1,
  sentenceData: [
    'Paragraph 1, Sentence 1',
    'Paragraph 1, Sentence 2'
  ]
},{
  id: 2,
  sentenceData: [
    'Paragraph 2, Sentence 1',
    'Paragraph 2, Sentence 2'
  ]
}];

var Sentence = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (<span
              contenteditable="true"
              onKeyDown={this.props.onKeyDown}>
              {this.props.value}
            </span>);
  }
});

var Paragraph = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var me = this;
    var sentences = this.props.sentenceData.map(function (sentenceData) {
      return <Sentence value={sentenceData} onKeyDown={me.props.onKeyDown} />;
    });

    return <div>{sentences}</div>;
});

var Document = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var me = this;
    var paragraphs = this.props.paragraphData.map(function (paragraphData) {
      return <Paragraph sentences={paragraphData.sentenceData} onKeyDown={me.onKeyDown}>;
    });

    return <div>{paragraphs}</div>;
  },
  onKeyDown: function (e) {
    // If "Enter" is pressed, I want to split the sentence at
    // getSelection().focusOffset, update the current sentence's
    // value to currentValue.substr(0, focusOffset) and insert a
    // new sentence with value currentValue.substr(focusOffset),
    // but how do I know which paragraph/sentences I need to
    // inspect/change?  Is "e.target" the only thing I have to go by?
  }
});
```

In ReactJS, the idea is for data to flow up and events to flow down.  (Which one is referred to as "up" or "down" seems to change all the time, but hopefully you know what I mean.)

### My Question:

In my onKeyDown handler, how do I know which models need to have changes applied?

I thought about using `.bind()` to bind the handler to each model as it was passed up, but it seems a bit... wrong:

- Would that be considered tight coupling between model/view?
- It would mean binding hundreds or thousands of times (potentially, on a large document), each time creating a new function - which would go against the best-practice "don't create functions in a loop" principle.

I get the feeling I'm heading in the wrong direction - any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to bind the onKeyDown function.

If you implement `shouldComponentUpdate` in `Sentence`, when your app is rendered again, the binded functions won't be created again because these components will not render if they have not change.

I don't think the memory overhead of 1000 or 10000 functions has too much impact, and you should not try to optimize this unless you have perf problems. What you don't want is create all these functions everytime on each render, and this is why `shouldComponentUpdate` is here.

It won't couple more your components that they are already (they are, because they interact together already on a well defined business context). Basically you could create a generic, uncoupled component that will receive any piece of data and on key down on the rendering of that data, will inject that data to a callback. It is generic and does not add coupling, you can control the entire behavior outside of the component.

---

Notice that binding functions coming from props or in loops to dom event listeners is not something forbidden by React and actually you can find exemples where it is done.

- In a loop (that may have many items!): http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html
- With binded function props: (can't find it, but I do use it myself...)

Notice that in React, it is forbidden to rebind a function of a component because React bind all functions to its component.
So if a function is in `Document` and is injected to `Sentence`, you can't bind it to `this` in `Sentence` because it does not make sens and is forbidden by React.

This is the code that does it: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/95de877dceeaac08755cfe1142a853c467d91d58/src/core/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L1291

```
if (newThis !== component && newThis !== null) {
          monitorCodeUse('react_bind_warning', { component: componentName });
          console.warn(
            'bind(): React component methods may only be bound to the ' +
            'component instance. See ' + componentName
          );
        }
```

Note that a `newThis !== null` has been added. This was actually added to fix this problem when trying to bind props functions.

Now you can write
 `<Sentence value={sentenceData} onKeyDown={me.props.onKeyDown.bind(null,sentenceData} />`

And on document you have a listener: 
`onKeyDown: function (sentenceData) { }`

This is perfectly fine :)

---

Notice that there is another way this problem can be solved which may be a little bit more efficient:

```
var Sentence = React.createClass({
  onKeyDown: function(e) {
     this.props.onKeyDown(this.props.value)
  },
  render: function () {
    return (<span
              contenteditable="true"
              onKeyDown={this.props.onKeyDown}>
              {this.props.value}
            </span>);
  }
});
```

Instead of binding a function, you simply create a class that has this unique function that you would normally bind. In this case I think however it creates more coupling as you don't really control the behavior of the callback from outside the `Sentence` component.

Comment: This is more like it!  However, I'm having trouble with `shouldComponentUpdate`: `nextProps` contains the same model as `props`, so any modifications to the model cannot be detected here :(

Comment: You have to use immutable data structures to do so. You can use this built-in tool: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html or you can use this more advanced library: https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js

Answer (score 0):

You're concerning yourself with the wrong problem.

Wherever the relevant onKeyDown handler that you're referring to should be working (i.e. for sentences, or paragraphs), you need to handle the data change and then call:

```
this.setState({stateName: newdata})
```

This will cause react to re-render the component with the new data.

For a good example, look at [facebook's tutorial for a comment widget](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#optimization-optimistic-updates).

You can see how the form handles the data change by adding new comments, and then calls setState() to re-render with the additional comments. React handles everything else.

In your example, if you change something within a paragraph, the paragraph should call setState with the new sentence data after you've done all the work you need, and then react will handle the rest.

Comment: But everything I've read tells me NOT to use `state` for the data itself, but to simply store information ABOUT the data.  And how could a `keydown` event within the `Sentence` span tell its parent `Paragraph` to split it in two, create a new `Sentence` and append it after the one that was modified (for example)?

Comment: Also, in my "split-sentence" example above, how do I tell React where to position the cursor after it has re-rendered?  It all just seems wrong...

Comment: Thus is how facebook shows to do it. The point is, you need to change the data and have react rerender. Thats it. Assuming you received the already split sentences as the initial data, react would render it properly. So you just need to make sure the data is is that state and then rerender, which is exactly what setState does.  You certainly dont want to touch the actual dom node.

Comment: I agree - definitely, but I can't take that concept and apply it to this concrete example.  A `Paragraph` manages its `Sentences`, so it makes sense the `keydown` handler would be on the `Paragraph` component, so the `Paragraph` can split the specific sentence using `setState`.  But again, how would it then specify which `Sentence` should have focus?  And where, within that `Sentence`, the Caret should be?